# How to use XPS (Transmit Packet Steering) from Kernel module

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

My scenario requires:

1. A Custom Loadable Kernel Module that composes packets(skbuffs) and tries to send them synchronously
2. Intel I40e driver (extracted from kernel source tree kernel version 4.15.12)

**Custom Loadable Kernel Module**

My packet is not a complex packet. I can initialize the packet during init phase of the module and use the same packet over and over. That's what I have done for the time being, as the communication jitter is important than the contents of the packet itself.

```
...
// I was doing
// txq = skb_get_tx_queue(skb->dev, skb);
// but it seemed that I will not be allowed to choose my desired queue in this case.

// thus, I tried to hardcode it for the time being.
txq =  &dev->_tx[7]; 
local_bh_disable();

HARD_TX_LOCK(skb->dev, txq, 7);

if (unlikely(netif_xmit_frozen_or_drv_stopped(txq))) {
    ret = NETDEV_TX_BUSY;
    goto unlock;
}
// prior to this approach, I was using ndo_start_xmit directly as
// skb->dev->netdev_ops->ndo_start_xmit(skb, skb->dev);
// but, with this I was not able to use XPS, thus I was trying [netdev_start_xmit()][1] [which ultimately invokes ndo_start_xmit]

ret = netdev_start_xmit(skb, skb->dev, txq, 0);

unlock:
HARD_TX_UNLOCK(skb->dev, txq);

local_bh_enable();

...
```

I have taken the packet transmission code reference from https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/net/core/pktgen.c#L3487

I am not sure if I am doing it right. The results do not say so. I was expecting my packets to flow through Tx Queue 7, but they are still flowing through the default one TX-Queue 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if somebody is looking for a quick dirty fix, modifications of the following two lines worked for me.

```
txq =  &dev->_tx[7]; 
local_bh_disable();
```

changed to

```
skb_set_queue_mapping(skb, 7);
txq = skb_get_tx_queue(dev, skb);
```

With this, I am able to steer my packets through Tx Queue 7, but I am still experiencing jitter, which is possibly originating from some other source.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19-rc3/ident/netdev_pick_tx

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19-rc3/ident/skb_set_queue_mapping

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/net/core/pktgen.c#L3487

Regards,

Cooshal.